# Module import error

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I have successfully installed pylab module on my Ubuntu and it works fine on call but when I run my Python script of plotting plot(pylab module imported) which is saved in a directory. It gives error which is indicating that error is due to a datetime.py file in the same folder. My program is just plotting a curve using pylab.I have not used datetime module in my program. 
My Program path is **/home/usr/python/plot.py**

```
import matplotlib
import pylab
pylab.figure(1)
pylab.plot([1,4,3],[1,4,9])
pylab.show()
```

**Exception**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "firstplot.py", line 1, in 
    import matplotlib
  File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-  x86_64.egg/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 156, in from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
  File "/home/aman/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-linux-  x86_64.egg/matplotlib/cbook.py", line 11, in 
     import datetime
  File "/home/aman/python/datetime.py ", line 1, in 
    from datetime import datetime
ImportError: cannot import name datetime
```

I tried to resolve this error.When i renamed datename.py file with someother name or just removed it.My program works fine.
This problem occurred because datetime.py is a standard module and i created another file with the same name in directory.May be when i runs my program it first searches standard modules in local directory and so giving error. But i couldn't understand the concept behind it why it is giving error because of datetime.py file or what is the working method of python when program calls a module.How it is located.Please help me to understand this logic.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path

Comment: that's mean if a module is called from a script which is inside a directory, then it first searches within local directory path and load all the scripts that are having same name like standard modules in standard library path.So it is creating error.We need to replace them or rename them. Am i getting it right? Please correct me if i am wrong!!

Comment: If using the provided interpreter executable, yes.